# How to produce colored code blocks in latex?

Tags: code

How can I write code block like this in Latex?

[image: block example]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

• Note this is a Q&A site, not a please do this for me service. What do you have so far.

Comment: read the documentation of `tcolorbox`

Comment: Use the `tcolorbox` and `minted` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. Read more in [The `tcolorbox` package manual](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{rgb}{0.56, 0.93, 0.56}
\definecolor{moonstoneblue}{rgb}{0.45, 0.66, 0.76}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=6mm,yshift=-3mm},
    colback=lightgreen!20,
    colframe=lightgreen,
    colbacktitle=lightgreen,
    title=C++ Code 1.1: C++ Example,
    fonttitle=\bfseries\color{black},
    boxed title style={size=small,colframe=lightgreen,sharp corners},
    sharp corners,
]
\begin{minted}[linenos]{cpp}
// This is a C++ code
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!";
}
\end{minted}
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=6mm,yshift=-3mm},
    colback=moonstoneblue!20,
    colframe=moonstoneblue,
    colbacktitle=moonstoneblue,
    title=Welcome to \TeX{} -- \LaTeX{} Stack Exchange!,
    fonttitle=\bfseries\color{black},
    boxed title style={size=small,colframe=moonstoneblue,sharp corners},
    sharp corners,
]
\begin{minted}[linenos]{latex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Einstein said $E=mc^2$!
\end{document}
\end{minted}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to reproduce the code above but the boxes appears empty.